MacOS Sequoia: keyboard shortcut for switching between apps open only inside a space
I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut that essentially performs <Cmd + Tab> to cycle through open applications, but limit that to only the ones open in a given space.
I generally have a lot of different apps open, so I organize them in different spaces according to a 'focus' in different spaces. Using <Cmd + Tab> becomes overwhelming when I'm only trying to cycle through the apps I have open right in front of me.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275

thanks, I don't want to toggle between windows of the same app, more interested in windows on the same space.
